# Upsert (merge) for updating record if it exists and inserting otherwise

Tags: sql, db2, upsert, zos

I am trying to write a DB2 query that allows me to either update a record if it already exists but if it does not exist it should be inserted. I wrote the following query that should accomplish this:

```
MERGE INTO OA1P.TLZ712A1 AS PC
USING (
    SELECT * FROM OA1P.TLZ712A1 
    WHERE CALENDAR_ID=13 AND 
    "PACKAGE"='M2108'
) PC2
ON (PC.ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR=PC2.ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET ACT_DATE = '31.12.2021'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ("PACKAGE", ACT_DATE, CALENDAR_ID, PREPTA, MIXED) VALUES ('M2108', '31.12.2021', 13, 0, 0)
```

This query should attempt to check if a record already exists for the selection criteria. Updating a record seems to be working fine but I am not able to get the "WHEN NOT MATCHED" part to work and inserting a new record. Anyone able to provide some assistance?

The table is used to save the activation date of a certain software package. `PACKAGE` is the reference to the package table containing the name of the package (eg. "M2108"). `CALENDAR_ID` refers to a system where the software package will be activated. The actual date is stored in `ACT_DATE`.

Did not manage to get the DDL into SQLFiddle so I have to provide it here:

```
CREATE TABLE OA1P.TLZ712A1 (
    ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR INTEGER DEFAULT IDENTITY GENERATED BY DEFAULT NOT NULL,
    CALENDAR_ID INTEGER,
    "PACKAGE" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ACT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PREPTA SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    MIXED SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "COMMENT" VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    LAST_MODIFIED_PID CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    ST_STARTID TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    ST_FROM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    ST_TO TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TLZ712A1_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR),
    CONSTRAINT CALENDAR FOREIGN KEY (CALENDAR_ID) REFERENCES OA1P.TLZ711A1(ID_CALENDAR) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT "PACKAGE" FOREIGN KEY ("PACKAGE") REFERENCES OA1P.TLZ716A1(NAME) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ILZ712A0 ON OA1P.TLZ712A1 (ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR);
```

Comment: Both tables are `OA1P.TLZ712A1` every `ID_PACKAGE_CALENDAR` that is in the `USING` clause is present in the merged table since PC2 is just a subset of PC. then `NOT MATCHED` can't happen

Comment: @nfgl Makes sense. My idea was that if the record is not found the `NOT MATCHED` would trigger. Do you know a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Please add the description of your table to your question (as text), also add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @nfgl I didn't manage to load the DDL into SQLFiddle but I updated the question with more information.

Comment: So your goal is to set `ACT_DATE` to 31.12.2021 if a row is found with `PACKAGE` = M2108 and `CALENDAR_ID` = 13 and if no row is found with these values then insert it. I'm I right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to set ACT_DATE to 31.12.2021 if a row is found with PACKAGE = M2108 and CALENDAR_ID = 13 and if no row is found with these values then insert it, then this could be the answer

```
MERGE INTO OA1P.TLZ712A1 AS PC
USING (
   VALUES ('M2108', 13, date '31.12.2021')
) PC2 ("PACKAGE", CALENDAR_ID, ACT_DATE)
ON (PC."PACKAGE", PC.CALENDAR_ID) = (PC2."PACKAGE", PC2.CALENDAR_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET ACT_DATE = PC2.ACT_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ("PACKAGE", ACT_DATE, CALENDAR_ID, PREPTA, MIXED) VALUES (PC2."PACKAGE", PC2.ACT_DATE, PC2.CALENDAR_ID, 0, 0)
```